# javax.el.ExpressionFactory Error when running Spring Boot Application on Google App Engine Standard

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot application on Google App Engine, however I receive the following error logs when attempting to call any of the APIs associated with the app.

> Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have
>   the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use
>   ParameterMessageInterpolator instead  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1406)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1368)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:522)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest(JavaRuntime.java:657)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest(JavaRuntime.java:619)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:589)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:783)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:263)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ProxyAsyncConfiguration':
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers'
>   parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'asyncConfiguration'

However, this error only occurs when I run my app on Google App Engine.  If I package it locally and run it, the app works as expected.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue?  Thanks you!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the el dependency;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also add a env-variables entry to your appengine-web.xml;

```
    <env-variables>
        <env-var name="javax.el.ExpressionFactory" value="com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl" />
    </env-variables>
```

And add the file 'META-INF/services/javax.el.ExpressionFactory'
with the contents:

```
    com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl
```

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to specify values with periods in as part of the environment variables any more - `Value 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory' for key in EnvironmentVariables does not match expression '^(?:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$'` is displayed during deployment. Using `system-properties` instead, as detailed in a [more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53627367/3674082), worked for me when using Java 8 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Krullert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46582248/7341640) I managed to fix the same problem for a java 8 application on app engine. I followed the steps of [Krullert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46582248/7341640)
The only extra thing I needed to do is add the 'WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services/javax.el.ExpressionFactory' file.

One remark: To be able to use 'org.glassfish:javax.el:3.0.1-b08' you need to work with servlet api version 3.1 ('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'). App engine standard now supports java 8 to be able to use that!

Comment: While links to external resources may be valuable, please include the solution directly in your answer here.

Comment: Hi Maciej, the link is to the previous answer of Krullert

Comment: Yeah well, that's precisely what I mean - either rephrase the answer and add your additions, or if you have nothing new to add then you should not be posting an answer - comment instead.